# custom validation on Google G-Suite Form with an add-on

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-forms

I am looking to do custom validation on a Google Form. I figure I need to add custom code to the form. The only events available are `on open` and `on submit`. `on open` is for when the form is opened for editing, not submitting. So there does not seem to be a way to add custom validation to the form this way.

I was looking at the various Form Add-on examples but all of them seem to modify the form edit experience. Is it possible to modify the form view/submission experience? Could I use an add-on to add custom validation (i.e. only weekends selected on a date field)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google doesn't offer a way to use code to customize the view/submission experience for Google Forms and add-ons can't add custom validation for the same reason.

One alternative among many others is to use Google Apps Script to create a web application.

Comment: Web Apps are not approved for use at my organization yet. I'm hoping it is soon. Can add-ons be used to do anything for form view/submission experience? Or are they only for form design experience?